# How do I get all the columns of a table besides one

Tags: sql

Suppose we have 20 columns in a table and I want to return 19 of them.
How can I do that ?

> select *

will give me all of them but I want only 19.

Is there a good solution for that situation ? something like

> select * - [columnName]

?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, sorry.  You can take `*`, or you can take them one at a time, but you can't take "all of them except for X, Y, or Z."

Answer (score 5):

As has been said, you use `SELECT *` for all columns or list the columns individually if you don't want them all.

Listing columns does seem like a chore but there is an important reason why it's actually good.

While it's OK for ad hoc queries, it's highly recommended that use don't use `SELECT *` in code because when the database schema changes you will get different columns in the results returned to your application which is almost certainly not what you want.  If you could do `select * but address from customer` this would have the same problem: changing the DB would change the structure of the results of your query which is bad.

So not only can you not do it, I would recommend not doing it even if you could.

Comment: Thanks for the best practice explanation

Comment: By your logic it would also be bad to explicitly list each column name, because the schema could change to make those column names no longer valid. You should write code that does what you need, if those needs change plan on refactoring. That's not to say planning ahead isn't prudent, but always plan on code changing when needs change.

Comment: @Myles: It's not the same. If you list the column names and the schema changes, your query fails right away and you know the reason why. If you `SELECT *` and the schema changes, your query will succeed and maybe your code will execute but get weird-but-non-obvious bugs because the data isn't what it is supposed to be.

It's not simply about the schema changing, but what happens when it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly name each column you wish to select. That is the only way to exclude columns.